# mqtt file transfer in nodejs?? (using mqtt.js)

Tags: node.js, mqtt

Right so I am trying to transfer some files using mqtt in nodejs.
This works fine if the file are tiny, but something as small a 6 mb rar file becomes 21 MB when it is turned into a string or buffer.

I need to have some details with the file like path and filename, so I have created an object that contains, the file buffer and the data I need. Once I have that, I Stringify it with JSON and can send it.

What is the best way to make sure that you get proper buffer size for mqtt transfer?

Thanks in advance.
Thomas

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt');

var fs = require('fs');
let client
let message
let bufferMessage
let data

function genPayload() {
  data = fs.readFileSync('app.rar');


  let message = {
    "filename": "app.rar",
    "filePath": "C:\\test\\",
    "data": data
  }

  console.log('Preparing File')
  bufferMessage = JSON.stringify(message);

}

function Connect() {
  client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://test.mosquitto.org", {
    clientId: "vfs001"
  });

  client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Client Connected')
  });
}

function SendFile() {
  client.publish('TestReplFile', bufferMessage)
  console.log('File is on the way')

};

genPayload();
Connect();
setTimeout(SendFile, 5000);
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `fs.readfileSync()` will return a Buffer and when you stringify that it will generate somethings that looks like:

```
...
data: [ 0x11, 0x44, 0xcf, ... ]
...
```

Which leads to at least 4 characters for every byte in the file.

To get the smallest JSON safe representation of a binary file you probably want to base64 encode it.

```
function genPayload() {
  data = fs.readFileSync('app.rar');

  let message = {
    "filename": "app.rar",
    "filePath": "C:\\test\\",
    "data": data.toString('base64')
  }

  console.log('Preparing File')
  bufferMessage = JSON.stringify(message);

}
```

Base64 will still be about 30% bigger than the input file, but it should still be smaller that a straight stringified buffer.

Comment: You are a life saver @hardillb, it is now working exactly like i would like to have it work.
Thank you very much for your help.